# How to make API request to backend (flask) from frontend(react) running in kubernetes?

Tags: reactjs, api, curl, kubernetes, axios

My react code:
http-commons.js

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://three-tier-backend-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

service.js

```
create(data) {
    return http.post("/add", data);
  }
```

When I tried the same command with curl inside the container by using kubectl exec

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Mat", "price": 5000, "breed": "Lab"}' http://three-tier-backend-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/add
```

I get the response:

```
{"name": "Mat", "price": 5000, "breed": "Lab"}
```

But the same request doesn't work in frontend in kubernetes
[Response in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXYAL.png)

Answer (score 0):

welcome on Stack Overflow

I think the main issue here is, that your Frontend javascript code (Axios + React) is executed at client-side.

Thus calling external service (three-tier-backend-svc.default.svc.cluster.local) from web browser, using DNS names reserved for Kubernetes in-cluster communication, is failing.

I would suggest you to take a look at three alternative options now:

1. [Expose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-the-service) your backend outside Kubernetes cluster with Service (LoadBalancer/NodePort types).
2. Expose you backend with [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress)
3. Consider changing your web app code to be server side rendered.